# List of statements which can be used to measure the value proposition of a website

Tags: usability-testing, surveys, heuristics

I'm looking for a list of statements that can be used to measure the value proposition of a website.

For example:

- The site is intuitive and easy to navigate.
- The site's content is well structured and easy to find what I'm looking for.
- The site is sociable.

I understand that these statements depends on the content of the site but if there is such a list out there, it would  help me to identify kind of questions that I can ask…

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "value proposition" since the example questions you give don't seem to relate to what I understand the term to mean?

Comment: Sorry, maybe 'value proposition' is not the correct word. The statements I'm looking for talks about the usability standards of the website. Member 'RK' below have given a link to 10 usability heuristics but they sounds too technical to general public.....

Comment: I'm still not clear on exactly what you are after. Let me try going at it from a different angle. If you had some good questions that let you know the value of the thing you are trying to measure - how would you use the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are searching for informal heuristics of sorts.

Read this [article on Smashing UX](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/16/guide-heuristic-website-reviews/). For a more formal evaluation you can look into nn/g's [10 Usability Heuristics for User Interface Design](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to rewrite the heuristics provided in the link in more general language:

The users is notified about changes and relevant information in a timely and appropriate manner.

The use of language, words, phrases and concepts are easily understood by the user, and the information is presented in a natural and logical way.

The user is able to recover from mistakes and can navigate different functions and features easily.

The system presents a consistent look and feel to the user at all times.

The system performs sensible validation of user input and provides clear checkpoints for users before they commit to important actions. Appropriate use of error messages and dialogs also prevent misunderstanding of information by the users.

The user is not overloaded with information, and the appropriate amount of content is provided at the point of need in a visible and clear manner.

The system can cater to both inexperienced and experienced users to provide a flexible and efficient use of the features.

Information which is irrelevant or rarely needed are not introduced in the user interface to maintain the optimal amount of detail.

Error messages are simple to understand and allows the user to resolve the issue raised if required.

The system provides useful help information with tooltips, hover-overs, in-line comments and message dialogs.